# ExtJS 4 checkbox

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I can't find a way to on/off check box in runtime in my fieldset definition:

```
       {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Do you want to add text file?',
            itemId: 'chorFileCheck',
            checkboxToggle: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    name: 'document',
                    fieldLabel: 'File',
                    labelWidth: 50,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    anchor: '100%',
                    regex: Portal.Const.DOC_ACCEPTED,
                    buttonText: 'Choose ...'
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
```

I can handle this check box by hand but can't find a way to do it in my code (make it in runtime). Prompt me please how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "but can't find a way to do int in my code"? Do you mean "but can't find a way to do it in my code"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `collapse()` and `expand()` methods of fieldset to **uncheck** & **check** the checkbox respectively.

For Unchecking the checkbox:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#chorFileCheck")[0].collapse();
```

For Checking the checkbox:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#chorFileCheck")[0].expand();
```

Comment: It was my first check. After "collapse" field is unchecked (light gray) but checkbox is still checked. That's my problem, how to uncheck checkbox.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?